# glReadPixels -> NSData -> save image

Tags: objective-c, opengl, save, writetofile

I create NSBitmapImageRep witch I fill with glReadPixels information. It looks like this:

```
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:3 hasAlpha:NO isPlanar:NO colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace bytesPerRow:3 * width bitsPerPixel:0];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [imageRep bitmapData]);
```

and later turn it to NSData and write to file. But I get flipped upside down image. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw into a flipped `NSImage`. This will draw the upsidedown image to the correct orientation. You then get the tiff representation of the `NSImage` which you can change to other image types using another `NSBitmapImageRep` with `imageRepWithData:`. Use the new image representation to make a new `NSData` object using `representationUsingType:properties:` and save the new `NSData` object to file.

```
    NSRect rect = self.bounds;
    NSSize size = rect.size;
    GLsizei width = (GLsizei)size.width;
    GLsizei height = (GLsizei)size.height;
    NSBitmapImageRep* imgRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:3 hasAlpha:NO isPlanar:NO colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace bytesPerRow:width*3 bitsPerPixel:0];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [imgRep bitmapData]);
#ifdef __MAC_10_8
    NSImage* image = [NSImage imageWithSize:size flipped:YES drawingHandler:^(NSRect dstRect){
        return [imgRep drawInRect:dstRect];
    }];
#else
    NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
    [image lockFocusFlipped:YES];
    [imgRep drawInRect:rect];
    [image unlockFocus];
#endif
    NSData* tiff = [image TIFFRepresentation];
```

Answer (score 0):

bytesPerRow should be `(width*3+3)&~3`